# Why NavigationController is not pusing the view?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I spent almost a day with this issue, someone please help me out! I'm trying to push the view from a tableview controller. It's not responding.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NewsDetailViewController *ndvc = [[NewsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ndvc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Verify ndvc is not nil. Verify that self.navigationController is not nil.

Comment: Well it seems to be nil and it's not getting in. What should I do?

Comment: Either `self.navigationController` is nil or `ndvc` is nil. Do you have navigation controller in project at all?

Comment: I dont have a navigationController, it's from table view controller!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that your `self.navigationController` is `nil`. And from the comments I get that you do not use a Navigation Controller. I would say, create a Window Based Application with the Navigation Controller as the `rootViewController` and inside that, add the `tableView` to the view of the `navigationController` and then you should have no problem.

Comment: Well, I need to mention that my tableViewController is inside the tabViewController. Do you think is the tabViewController causing this issue?

Comment: No. You need to put the navigationController inside the tabViewController, and inside that you need to add the `tableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Your NewsDetailViewController likely overrides initWithNibName function.  Use breakpoints to see why this is returning nil.  Make sure you are passing the right NIB file name (i.e. make sure NewsDetailViewController.xib exists in your project)